# How can I retrieve the dropdown state of a DateTimePicker?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datetimepicker

I'm needing to determine if the calendar dropdown is currently being shown in a WinForms DateTimePicker.  I've got a custom control that inherits from DateTimePicker, and I'm handling the KeyDown event in order to do stuff with navigation keys, but I'd like to bypass that code if the calendar dropdown is open, so that the user can use their navigation keys there.

With the ComboBox control, it is easy to use the `.DroppedDown` property to check if it's open, but DateTimePicker doesn't have a property like this.

I'm currently doing the following:

```
Private _isDroppedDown As Boolean = False

Private Sub MyDateTimePicker_CloseUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.CloseUp
    _isDroppedDown = False
End Sub

Private Sub MyDateTimePicker_DropDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.DropDown
    _isDroppedDown = True
End Sub
```

However, I'd like to know if there's a better way to get the DroppedDown state of the control than manually keeping track of it with a variable?

Comment: DTP is a bit lame, nothing wrong with what you have now.

Comment: It works, but isn't too elegant.  As it turns out, other limitations of the Windows DTP are also giving me problems, so I'll just roll my own instead.

Comment: Please write this as an answer, Hans, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've done is fine for one-off instances, but if your form/class contains multiple controls, tracking them *all* with variables can become unwieldy and difficult to follow.

A simple alternative method is to use the control's `.Tag` property to record the variable state and test that. However, a better method is to create your own class that inherits the control and add the property you want, pretty much using the same code you already have. So, in your case, you would add a class called say "MyDateTimePicker" with this code:

```
Public Class MyDateTimePicker
    Inherits DateTimePicker

    Dim _isDroppedDown As Boolean = False

    Public Property IsDroppedDown() As Boolean
        Get
            IsDroppedDown = _isDroppedDown
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _isDroppedDown = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub MyDateTimePicker_CloseUp(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.CloseUp
        _isDroppedDown = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub MyDateTimePicker_DropDown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.DropDown
        _isDroppedDown = True
    End Sub

End Class
```

After the next build, the new MyDateTimePicker class should appear in your toolbox under the project's 'Components' tab. It will have all of the usual events, methods and properties associated with DateTimePickers, plus your new `.IsDroppedDown` property.

Oh and if it's something you use regularly you could create it as a new class library and simply include the DLL it builds in your projects.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing now, I was just wondering if there's a method of getting the state without the use of an internal variable.

Comment: Sorry, I obviously missed the part of your OP that mentioned it was a custom control inheriting from the DTP – that'll teach me to read questions more carefully in future. So anyway, what is it about this method you don't like? Admittedly it would be better if the DTP had such a property already built in, but since it doesn't, this seems to be the best workaround. It's certainly better, in my opinion, than delving into subclassing etc.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some sort of sub-property somewhere where I could retrieve the information without tracking it myself.  As it is, because of some other limitations of the DTP, I'm now looking at basing my class on the TextBox instead.

Comment: @MCattle Fair enough. I must admit I find the shortcomings of the standard .NET date controls very frustrating. I did once toy with the idea of using a WPF Calendar control within a WinForms app, but it's sadly just as fettered with problems (albeit different ones) as the WinForms MonthCalendar control is. MS are seemingly as bad at making date/time controls as they are at making scrollbars!

Comment: This answer is pretty handy: just paste the code in a custom controller, and replace your previous calls. Thanks man, for verbosing the OP code.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a better way of achieving this; the current code is just fine.

(Just posting this answer to close the question.  I've since moved on from trying to build on the DTP class.)